# How to make a modal responsive in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple modal in react. I'm trying to make it responsive. When it's a desktop, its height and width is fixed. When it's a desktop and the modal is open, the background should not be scrollable. Only the modal should be scrollable. When it's a mobile, the modal takes full full width and height.

I've managed to get the modal to work but having issues making the modal full width and height when its a mobile. I'm also having issues making the background not scrollable.

I've created an example on code-sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-bulma-modal-u2tyd

Comment: If you're learning react, don't waste time with css, use materialui or antd or reactstrap or semanticui or whatever you like to do all of this

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed, IMO, this is a bad advise. Why someone should NOT learn CSS and rely on frameworks built? One SHOULD definitely learn the basics. Frameworks are not always the preferred choice.

Comment: No one said he shouldn't learn CSS, I've told him to focus on react in the mean time

Answer (score 0):

You are using `bulma` to style your html which do not provide styles you required for mobile devices out of the box, so you need to add them manually. There are several options how to do that. One of them: you need to create `css` class and "wrap" it into media query `@media` so that you can detect device width and apply appropriate styles:

```
// Add this to your styles.css file

@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .modal-card-customization {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
}

// And apply this class for the modal in index.js file

// .... your previous code here

  <div className="modal-background" />
  <div className="modal-card modal-card-customization">

// .... rest of your code here
```

In order to disable scrollbar once the modal is open you can apply `overflow: hidden` style on `document.body`, like so:

```
    // index.js file

//.... your previous code here

    const active = this.state.isModal ? "is-active" : "";
    
    if (active) {
      document.body.style = 'height: 100vh; overflow: hidden';
    } else {
      document.body.style = ''
    }
    
//.... rest of your code here
```